# active record join two tables with where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model

```
class PatientProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships

  with_options through: :friendships, source: :friend do |model|
    model.has_many :friends, -> { where(friendships: { status: 'accepted'}) }
    model.has_many :friend_requests, -> { where(friendships: { status: 'requested'}) }
    model.has_many :requested_friendships, -> { where(friendships: { status: 'requestor'}) }
  end
```

`uids = ["123", "456"]`

I'd like to query `PatientProfile` to find all records where uid is in the uids array and there are no records of friendships between the two users.

This should be possible with a join but I'm getting tripped up in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

EDIT:

`uid` is on `PatientProfile`

On the `Friendships` table there are two columns, `friend_id` and `patient_profile_id`. I only want the `PatientProfile`'s where `friend` is not in the list of `uids` and `patient_profile_id` is not, say, 1

Comment: ... and `uid` column belongs to which model ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit `PatientProfile`

Comment: how do you generate the `uid` list?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ it comes back from a 3rd party

Comment: @user2954587 via request outside of the rails app?

Answer (score 0):

We're missing some context about what you mean with no records of friendships, but if you're looking for the records, having 0 friendships with the uids it would be:

```
PatientProfile.includes(:friendships).where(uid: [123, 456], friendships: {id: nil})
```

**update**

Or if you prefer a scoped version:

```
scope :no_friendships, -> { includes(:friendships).where(friendships: {id: nil}) }
```

So now you can do:

```
PatientProfile.no_friendships.where(uid: [123, 456])
```

Comment: *there are no records of friendships between the two users* lines from OP made me confused.

Comment: I updated the question with more information that is hopefully helpful, apologies for the confusion